# 'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency

Tags: swift, async-await

I'm trying to use async/await with Swift 5.5.  I have my async function, but whenever I try to call it, I get this error:

> 'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency

Here's the code sample:

```swift
class TryThis {
    func getSomethingLater(_ number: Double) async -> String {
        // test - sleep for 3 seconds, then return
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
        return String(format: ">>>%8.2f<<<", number)
    }
}

let tryThis = TryThis()

let result = await tryThis.getSomethingLater(3.141592653589793238462)
print("result: \(result)")
```

What's the solution for this??

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The answer here is that the "await getSomethingLater" must be called from an async context.  Literally that means changing this:

```swift
let result = await tryThis.getSomethingLater(3.141592653589793238462)
print("result: \(result)")
```

into this:

```swift
Task {
    let result = await tryThis.getSomethingLater(3.141592653589793238462)
    print("result: \(result)")
}
```

So the whole thing becomes:

```swift
class TryThis {
    func getSomethingLater(_ number: Double) async -> String {
        // test - sleep for 3 seconds, then return
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
        return String(format: ">>>%8.2f<<<", number)
    }
}

let tryThis = TryThis()

Task {
    let result = await tryThis.getSomethingLater(3.141592653589793238462)
    print("result: \(result)")
}
```

Here's the output:

> result: >>>    3.14<<<

There's great info in the [Meet async/await in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132) video from WWDC21.

Comment: I get the warning `'async(priority:operation:)' is deprecated: `async` was replaced by `Task.init` and will be removed shortly.`. I think that means this answer should no longer be accepted.

Comment: @Ky The answer as it stands does not use 'async(priority:operation:)'. Its replacement, as you mentioned, is to use Task, which this answer is using. This is the correct answer.

Comment: Just a note: You can use `.pi` instead of a literal: `tryThis.getSomethingLater(.pi)`

Answer (score 14):

When calling `async` code (including `actor` fields) from non-`async` code, you have to wrap it in a `Task`:

```swift
Task {
    let result = await tryThis.getSomethingLater(3.141592653589793238462)
    print("result: \(result)")
}
```

If you need it to escape that async context, you can use traditional callbacks:

```swift
func awaitedResult(callback: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    Task {
        let result = await tryThis.getSomethingLater(3.141592653589793238462)
        callback(result)
    }
}

awaitedResult { result in
    print("result: \(result)")
}
```

[Swift by Sundell](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/creating-combine-compatible-versions-of-async-await-apis/) also offers some alternatives involving Combine

---

Further reading: [Concurrency — The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.5)](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID642)

Comment: Good answer, only that I found that you now also need @escaping on the callback.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks, @kapace; that's what I get for writing this in the SO editor without checking it in a compiler 

Answer (score 5):

The original error is produced because "top-level" await is not yet supported in Swift (that is, code at the global scope).
The error just means you need to provide the async function with an asynchronous context, like using `Task`, `Task.detached` or a `TaskGroup`, depending on the behaviour you want.

```swift
Task.detached {
    let result = await tryThis.getSomethingLater(3.141592653589793238462)
    print("result: \(result)")
}
```

However, your code snippet should work in the future when top-level await is eventually proposed, implemented and supported.
Top-level await support was mentioned as part of the original proposal for async/await [SE-0296](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0296-async-await.md#launching-async-tasks).

Answer (score 2):

In my case I just refactored the:

```
async { some-code-which-can-take-some-time }
```

with:

```
Task { some-code-which-can-take-some-time }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you’ve tried to call an async function from a synchronous function, which is not allowed in Swift – asynchronous functions must be able to suspend themselves and their callers, and synchronous functions simply don’t know how to do that.

```
func doAsyncWork() async {
    print("Doing async work")
}

func doRegularWork() {
    Task {
        await doAsyncWork()
    }
}
```

doRegularWork()

[Reference here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-fix-the-error-async-call-in-a-function-that-does-not-support-concurrency)